# Pine script cannot return an array of linefills Pine script v5 [Bug report]

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

> **Study Error**
> Internal server pine compilation error

This basic example throws the exception above.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test")

test() =>
    foo = line.new(bar_index,  close, bar_index + 1,  close, xloc.bar_index, color = color.red)
    bar = line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index + 1, open, xloc.bar_index, color = color.green)

    lf = linefill.new(foo, bar, color.new(color.red, 80))
    
    array.from(lf) // we want to return n number of linefills 

lf = test()
```

Is there a particular reason for that? I cannot think of any reason why a simple data type should be exempt from being returned as an array. It seems to be a pine script bug again.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Thanks for the report. I will forward this to the dev team.

Comment: Thanks @vitruvius for the confirmation. I've done it myself too. In case my ticket gets closed, please feel free to edit my question with the updates from the dev team. Last time it took approximately a month to fix a bug, which, based on the severity, I consider absolutely fair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today (**2022-10-03**), **the bug was confirmed** by the TradingView Pine Team and a task was opened to fix it.
**Only workaround for now** is to return a tuple of all the linefills there are like this:

```
test() =>  
    ...  
    [lf1, lf2, lf3]  

[linefill1, linefill2, linefill3] = test()
```